# is there a way to do a bidirectionnal relationship with entity inheritance.joined in JPA with discrimanator value?

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance, entity, joined-subclass

I have a ValuedCustomer and Order and I want to do a bidirectional relationship in hibernate. How do I do this? Thanks

```
@Entity
@Table(name="VCUST")
@DiscriminatorValue("VCUST")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="CUST_ID",referencedColumnName="ID"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="CUST_TYPE",referencedColumnName="TYPE")
})
public class ValuedCustomer extends Customer { 

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)

    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_order", nullable = true)

    private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<>();

}


@Entity
@Table(name=“Order”)
public class Order { 

@Id
private int id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's easy. Important is the mappedBy attribute in @OneToMany that indicates that the realtionship is managed by the Order entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="VCUST")
@DiscriminatorValue("VCUST")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="CUST_ID",referencedColumnName="ID"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="CUST_TYPE",referencedColumnName="TYPE")
})
public class ValuedCustomer extends Customer { 

   @OneToMany(mappedBy= 'valuedCustomer" fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
   private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name=“Order”)
public class Order { 

   @Id
   private int id;

   @ManyToOne
   private ValuedCustomer valuedCustomer;


}
```